# Attribute Routing over Convention-based Routing in MVC, which one would be called first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am assuming that the convention routing would be added to the route table first because it is getting registered in the global.asax file like this

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Now I have a route like this in the route.config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{            
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

and I have an attribute route like this

```
[Route("students/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

Now when I use the URL

> localhost:4200//students

The students route is getting called successfully but when I use the route like this

> localhost:4200//students/40

I get error, I don't know the reason why. When I remove the route from **RouteConfig** class I am able to call it successfully.

Can anyone explain me why and how?

Comment: I think the call to MapMvcAttributeRoutes must be before MapRoute calls.

Comment: are u sure? as per the doc in msdn it is not

Comment: routes are called in the order they are added to the routing table. First match wins and it does not do any further checks. Targeted attribute routes are usually added before more generic convention based routes to avoid route conflicts.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj No doc is going to show you attribute routes being added after convention based routes unless it was a typo.

Comment: thanks @Nkosi it works

Comment: thanks @Penguin it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original example the URL `localhost:4200//students/40` is being matched to the `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` convention-based route template.

But since there is no action called `40` it will fail.

Now because it has already matched a route, it will not check any further for other matches so you will end up with Not Found error.

In Asp.Net MVC, routes are called in the order they are added to the routing table. First match wins and it does not do any further checks.

Targeted attribute routes are usually added before more general convention based routes to avoid route conflicts like the one experienced in your example.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { 
    //Attribute routes
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //Convention-based routes.
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```